# Issue saving to NSApplicationSupportDirectory

Tags: ios, ipad, nsfilemanager

I'm having a strange issue saving to NSApplicationSupportDirectory on my iPad app.

I've been using this data structure for a long time with no issues, it only appears during the first two loads of the program.

The first time the app opens, I open up a file from the mainBundle and re-save it as a default settings file, which is then used to store any changes to settings in the application.

The second time I open the app, the file doesn't seem to exist yet, so it creates it again!  The third time and after, all is well.  I can't figure out why it isn't saving it the first time.

Sorry if this is messy - it's a part of hundreds of pages of code!

Here's my initialization:

```
///inside the init of the object
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError* err = nil;

    NSURL* dir = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory 
                                     inDomain:NSUserDomainMask 
                            appropriateForURL:nil 
                                       create:YES 
                                        error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"error finding app support directory %@", err);
    }

    currentSettingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kCurrentSettingsFilename relativeToURL:dir]; 



    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[currentSettingsURL path]])[self createDefaultFile];

    NSArray* files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[dir path] error:&err];
    NSLog(@"files %@", files);
```

where the file is created if it doesn't exist.

```
-(void)createDefaultFile{
NSURL* readURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"smooth" withExtension:nil];    
NSMutableData* tempData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:readURL]; 
NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:tempData];


///re archive
[self setCurrentPresets:[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"presetData"]];

}

-(void)setCurrentPresets:(NSMutableArray*)presets{
currentPresets = presets;
[self saveCurrentSettings];
}
```

here is where the file is saved

```
-(void)saveCurrentSettings{
data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:currentPresets forKey:kCurrentSettingsFilename];
[archiver finishEncoding];  


if(![data writeToURL:currentSettingsURL atomically:YES])NSLog(@"error saving file");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply needed to tell it my NSApplicationSupportDirectory was a folder..

```
NSURL* dir = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory 
                        inDomain:NSUserDomainMask 
               appropriateForURL:nil 
                          create:YES 
                           error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"error finding app support directory %@", err);
    }

    NSURL* folder = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[dir path] isDirectory:YES];
    currentSettingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kCurrentSettingsFilename relativeToURL:folder];
```